# Which tool for Laravel?

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel-4

I'm a newbie PHP developer now casting an eye at frameworks, especially at Laravel 4 since from what I've heard it's one of the fastest to learn and most elegant ones. However, what's still not so clear to me is how, i.e. in which tool/IDE to actually code Laravel projects? Does Laravel include its own or recommend any specific IDE or can (and should) I just continue to use the one I'm already familiar with, which in my case is Netbeans (which provides no native support for Laravel 4 but according plugins, besides many nice features like code completion, integrated Xdebug, versioning...)?

Thanks!

Comment: Any good IDE would do, really. A framework it's just a structured collection of php classes and functions

Comment: don't focus on IDE, it will bring complexity if your newbie, better take text editor first like sublime text, coda, notepad++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been said already, Laravel doesn't require any special tools to use, so any good text editor or IDE will work for you and it's a matter of personal preference. IMHO, [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is generally a joy to use, and with the [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) you get autocompletion with the Laravel facades, which can save you a lot of digging in the docs. There's also a [Blade syntax highlighter plugin](https://github.com/outofcontrol/Blade.tmbundle), though that doesn't provide autocomplete. PHPStorm 8 natively supports Blade.

The IDE helper will also work with Netbeans.

Laravel is great at providing everything you need out of the box, and for some projects it provides far more than you need. If you want to keep your project as lightweight as possible and don't mind choosing your own plugins, you could try [Aura](http://auraphp.com/) instead.

Comment: +1 for aura :) . For convenience the url is http://auraphp.com/ , https://github.com/auraphp . Remember most of libraries have 2 versions. `develop` branch is v1, and `develop-2` is version 2.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is almost similar to Cake PHP. I am a Cake PHP developer. Even I had the same problem but I'll advice you to go for Net Beans. It is the best suited for MVC (Model, View , Controller) projects. Both Laravel and Cake PHP are based on MVC so I'll advice you to go for it.

Comment: `Net Beans. It is the best suited for MVC` Could you explain this statement? It doesn't make much sense as it stands

Comment: by using Net Beans we can recover data from our history of code( 30 days retrieval time). along with that Net Beans has a Cake PHP plugin. By using that we can specify that we are creating a controller or model & Net Beans will automatically extend it to the AppController or AppModel(in case of Cake PHP)